# Click event does not properly propagate to parent DOM node in Firefox using vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, dom, vue.js

Consider the following component in vue.js v2:

```
<template>
    <a @click="doSomething()">
        <i class="some-icon"></i>
    </a>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            doSomething() {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I got a strange problem here. The `click` event is properly triggered on the `<a>` element in both Chrome and Firefox. But when I click on the contained `<i>` element, the `click` event on the `<a>` element won't fire in Firefox. In Chrome, the `doSomething()` method is triggered when clicking the `<i>` element, in Firefox, it just doesn't happen.

Is this a known issue? Can I manually propagate the click in an elegant way in vue.js?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue https://jsfiddle.net/5fmsy0ov/4/ - most probably this is a styling issue where your anchor element is not actually wrapping the `i` anymore

Comment: Can't reproduct this either - and if this actually was a problem, our issue tracker on github would be flooded with bug reports. does the CSS on the `<i>` have any CSS like `pointer-events: none;`?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I'll have to look into this tomorrow or on friday and I'll try to get back when I found the issue.